# What is a good word I can use for the talking I do with myself in my mind?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*'Monologue'* seems like a close fit, but I think more people associate it with one-sided conversation. Correct me if I'm wrong.

*'Soliloquy'* seems to be only concerned with plays and dramas.

Can I use something like '*inner monologue'* to convey my precise intention? Or is *'monologue'* enough? Any other good word or way to do the same?

Comment: "Interior monolog" is a fairly common term for this.

Comment: It's a sort of analysis within your mind. Self-analysis. There's no "talking" there actually. If you clarify this, it'd be easier to find the right term.

Comment: @Sankarane I mean talking we do in our mind with ourselves. I just coined a quote and looking for a better word to replace monologue. I think 'inner monologue' looks good. :)

Comment: @Sankarane - Wadaya mean "no talking"??  Heck, sometimes I get in arguments with myself.  (And, seriously, who hasn't caught themselves actually mumbling the words they're thinking?)

Comment: "Interior monolog" was [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inner+monolog%2Cinternal+monolog%2Cinterior+monolog&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinner%20monolog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinternal%20monolog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterior%20monolog%3B%2Cc0) until the mid 90s when, for some reason, "internal monolog" shot upward.  "Inner monolog" is a non-starter.

Comment: @HotLicks If you could pick one in a quote, what would you pick? - 'Inner monologue' vs 'Interior monologue' vs 'internal monologue'.

Comment: I've always used "internal monolog".  But, then, I've been living in a cave since about 1990.

Comment: Have you ever tried getting decent WiFi reception in a cave?  It's the pits.  And the bears next door just put a password on their router, so now I have to go out to the berry patch to get reception.

Comment: You got such a great sense of humor @HotLicks!! :)

Comment: You know what THEY say @Hot Licks (they're always sayin' something), "*If you can't beat 'em ...bring 'em berries!*"

Comment: @Hot Licks: You may have a "conversation with yourself" inside a cave, I mean with the echos! What I wanted to know is whether the OP was referring to speaking out or just a back-and-forth dialogue inside the mind.

Comment: Try the more accurate -ue- endings for monologue: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inner+monologue%2Cinternal+monologue%2Cinterior+monologue&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&  Dialog is more common than dialogue, but monologue is still more popular than monolog

Comment: Sure @Mitch! :)

Comment: [Dialog is more common than dialogue](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialog%2Cdialogue&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), but [monologue is still more popular than monolog](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monolog%2C+monologue&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Mitch - Yep, you're right -- "interior monologue" swamps all the others, going back to the 20s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Austin Powers used the term "[inner monologue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpNoaR_Nzrs&t=4m22s)".

"Subvocalization" could also be used, but it usually refers to when reading or reciting something silently.

Comment: That's nice term to use and thanks for the video too! :)

Answer (score 1):

***[Stream of consciousness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stream+of+consciousness)/thought***:

> - A literary technique that presents the thoughts and feelings of a character as they occur.
> - Psychology The conscious experience of an individual regarded as a continuous, flowing series of images and ideas running through the mind.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: I liked the phrase a lot @Josh61.

Comment: A 'stream of consciousness' is probably what the OP is doing, but the literary/psychological term is usually associated with inarticulate rambling. The OP probably wants something that makes it seem more like a coherent narrative (the narration/monologue of the movie of his own life).

Answer (score 1):

**self-talk**. noun.

> 1. the act or practice of talking to oneself, either aloud or silently and mentally: positive self-talk. Contemporary definitions for
>      self-talk.
>
> https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=self-talk+definition

Answer (score 1):

**Internal monologue**, also known as inner voice, internal speech, or verbal stream of consciousness is thinking in words. It also refers to the semi-constant internal monologue one has with oneself at a conscious or semi-conscious level

https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=inner+voice

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't actually speaking out (verbally to yourself like we catch ourselves doing it at times, albeit involuntarily), then it's a "dialogue with your self". (Note: not "yourself"!). This may be just **introspection** (observation or examination of one's own mental and emotional state, mental processes, etc.; the act of looking within oneself).

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this as *internal narration*.

---

I happen to have such a narrator in my head. He provides an unending stream of occasionally strange but consistently colorful commentary, in Rod Serling's voice, upon both my thoughts and the moment-to-moment events of my life.

---

[**My Inner Narrator is *Obnoxious***](http://isitnormal.com/story/my-inner-narrator-is-obnoxious-72307/)

[**The Narrator in My Head**](https://snukes.wordpress.com/2007/09/07/the-narrator-in-my-head/)

[**Does your Life have a Narrator?**](http://intpexperience.com/mybb/showthread.php?tid=86)

Answer (score -1):

How about *reverie*, meaning lost in one’s thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jean Murray. :) I think it is somewhat more inclined to day dreaming. :)